# how to upload multiple files with ajax and explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

How can i upload multiple files with ajax when browsing?

This is my html:

```
<p><input class="browse" type="button" value="Browse" onclick="file_explorer();"></p>
<input type="file" id="selectfile" multiple>
```

And the js:

```
function file_explorer() {
        document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
        document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
            for (var i=0; i< e.dataTransfer.files.length;i++){ // multiple files
              fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[i];
              ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
            }
        };
    }

 function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
    if(file_obj != undefined) {
        var form_data = new FormData(); 
        form_data.append('file', file_obj);
      $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,

        success:function(response) {
          $(".success").html(response);
          $('#selectfile').val('');

        }

      });
    }
  }
```

This, below, does work fine for 1 file:

```
function file_explorer() {
        document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
        document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function()                 
              fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[0];
              ajax_file_upload(fileobj);

        };
    }
```

For multiple i tried this but unfortunately, it does not work:

```
function file_explorer() {
        document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
        document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
            for (var i=0; i< e.dataTransfer.files.length;i++){
              fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[i];
              ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
            }
        };
    }
```

How can i make this work properly for multiple files?

Comment: did you `console.log(e.dataTransfer.files.length)` ??

Comment: I think you can try `this.files.length` .. I'm not expert on plain javascript but you can try

Comment: Awesome! Works great now! `for (var i=0; i< this.files.length;i++){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with your code you got the error `e` is not defined so you can change `e.dataTransfer` with `this` .. see an example below

```js
document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
  for (var i=0; i< this.files.length;i++){
    fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[i];
    console.log(fileobj.name);
    //ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="selectfile" multiple>
```

Comment: Works great now! Thnx

Comment: glad to hear that .. Have a great day @JackMaessen :)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get this working by making small changes to your code:
1. e not defined - so let e = document.getElementById('selectfile')
2. replace e.dataTransfer.files.length  with e.files.length